# Target still runs eventhough it exists

Tags: makefile

I have a process which takes a long time to run so I am using Make to manage it so it doesn't have to run if its already done.

```
compile:
        sleep 600 && touch $@
present: compile
        cat compile
```

When I do `make present` it does a compile and present and if I do it again it does it again. My desired behavour is it only does present

Using GNUMake 3.82

`

Comment: When I try that with GNU make, it fails because it expects `$@` rather than `>@`. After I change that, it works.

Comment: changed. had a typo. strange that it still doesn't work. I even did touch compile in the shell and then do make present and still does the whole thing

Comment: What kind of make are you using? `make -v`

Comment: Don't know if updating is viable in your situation, but 3.82 is 8 years old. The working version I tried has version 4.2.1

Comment: The makefile you show should not behave like that, even with 3.82.  That's the most basic capability of make.  I recommend you run `make -d` and examine the output to see why it decides that `compile` needs to be rebuilt.  I'm confident it's due to some other aspect of your system or environment, that you haven't shared with us.

Comment: make -d did the trick. I had another issue with file timestamp.